# How do I parseInt out the hyphens " -" in a Credit Card Function in JS

Tags: javascript

Here is my function and I want it to return the credit card number without the hyphens "-".  But it stops when it reaches the first hyphen and only return "589".  What am I missing?

```
var creditCardParse = function(creditCards) {
    return parseInt(creditCards);
};
    creditCardParse("589-65-9878");
```

Returns "589"

Comment: creditCards.split('-')

Comment: Why are you parsing to an int at all?  Aside from probable overflow and leading zero errors, you're not going to be doing math with it.  Just use `creditCards.replace("-", "")`.

Comment: @PaulAbbott I agree. This is something many programmers struggle with - if some data contains only numbers it's not necessarily supposed to be numeric. As a rule of thumb, it's only numeric if you're going to do mathematical operations on it - e.g., weight, length, score. If not, it's a string - e.g., phone numbers, credit card numbers, IP addresses.

Answer (score 1):

You don't, you remove them before parsing

```
var creditCardParse = function(creditCards) {
    return parseInt(creditCards.replace(/\D/g,''),10);
};

creditCardParse("589-65-9878"); // 589659878
```

Comment: `creditCardParse("9007-1992-5474-0999") // -> 9007199254741000` Sure, I cheated and took `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` (9007199254740991) and swapped the last number to a nine. I don't expect this to be a valid credit card number, but it's here to show that _treating this number as a number_ can lead to problems. This is a plain 16 digit card number and I can't remember if there are any that start with nine, which might be a problem. I do know that some cards can have _more_ than 16 digits and each will be a potential problem.

Comment: @vlaz - sure, large numbers could be a problem. I have idea how large numbers credit cards can have, I don't even know why the OP needs integers and not just strings, heck, I don't even understand why the OP is dealing with credit card numbers at all, I thought everyone used a service like Stripe for that these days, and stayed away from messing with things that they shouldn't be messing with unless they know a lot about securely handling peoples money,  I just answered the question?

Comment: I do agree with everything you said and I do agree this is an accurate answer to OP's question. However, if somebody else looks at the question, and they decide to read the comment, they might decide that this is the wrong approach. Unfortunately, it's one of the instances on SO where you can have an accurate solution which is not necessarily _correct_ in a more general sense. I don't think a downvote is warranted in that case, for the answer is not _wrong_ or unhelpful. I also don't feel like an upvote is _right_ as the problem being solved is incorrect. Therefore, I leave a comment.

Comment: thanks for this response - btw this is a learning exercise so your comments are very helpful.

Comment: I did have one more question -  is there anyway to replace "10" so I can run credit cards of different lengths thru the function without having to change the code in the return line?

Comment: The number `10` does not reflect the length of the string, but the radix, meaning it parses it in base 10